# VueJS 2: Local assets

Tags: vuejs2

I made a project with the cli and I have some css and js files in the assets folder that was generated. I am trying to add them to the `index.html` file but it keeps coming back as a 404. Is there a different way I need to add my local css and javascript files?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the webpack template, try `/src/assets/...` in the `index.html`

Comment: Still 404 and I am using the webpack template

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack config file, you can add an alias for your `assets` folder:

```
module.exports = { 
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
},
```

Then, in your application, you can reference this folder like so:

```
// in a .less file
@import "~assets/css/vars"
```

```
// in a .js file
require("assets/js/utils")
```

Comment: This did not fix the problem either, still a 404

Comment: @CalebBassham are you sure you are setting the alias correctly? Is your assets folder at `../src/assets` relative to your config file?