# How to put a link to assets/pdf in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Hello I just want to put a link to PDF file but it's impossible. There is a library in npm or by another way to do that in VUEJS

I checked this link but it doesn't work

> [VueJS 2: Local assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059936/vuejs-2-local-assets)

// template

```
<img src="~assets/images/wtd.jpg">
```

// image folder

[image: image folder]

// error

[image: error]

**SOLUTION**

For images just use

```
<img src="@/assets/images/image.jpg">
```

For pdf just put your file in static folder and use this link. In my case I use

```
<a href="../../static/mypdf.pdf">
```

Comment: src= is webpack included, is `<a href="../../static/mypdf.pdf">` as well? i doubt it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the project created by vue-cli, then below syntax will work
e.g

```
<img src="@/assets/images/{{imageName}}.png"/>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This code works well with <img src=""> but not with <a href="">

Comment: With href you do not serve any assets. Href contains URL.

Comment: You mean It's not possible to link button to a image page like google image ?

Comment: In that case. you need to wrap image with anchor tag

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how to do that can you explain me and is it possible to do that with pdf files ? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I will share an example with you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190514/discussion-between-varit05-and-wmonteiro).

Answer (score 0):

With webpack, you can bundle assets with CopyWebpackPlugin.
Have a look at this webpack.config.js, it uses assets. https://github.com/BlueForestTrees/web/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Inside plugins section:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([{from: './img', to: 'img'}]),
```

Comment: Are you sure? You may find your assets in the dist folder after a build. Take care about the paths and so on.

Comment: I didn't launch build command, I'm working locally why should I build ?

Answer (score 0):

If you used vue-cli to create the project. The default image type of 'png|jpe?g|gif|webp' is default supported
In template you can use

```
<img src="~assets/images/demo.png"/>
```

In script you can use

```
const demo = require("@/assets/images/demo.png") // @ is a alias in webpack config
```

or:

```
import demo from "@/assets/images/demo.png")
```

For the .pdf file, there is no default loader for this type file. You need config a loader like url-loader for this: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack

Comment: I tried to use ~assets/images/myimage.jpg I get an error, I put update in my post